# Is there anything wrong or prejudicial in stoicism?

Tags: job

I'm reading the book of Job, and there is a footnote noting that Job is not a stoic but a man who suffers. I wondered if there's anything wrong with the stoic perspective relating to suffering. I feel that the stoic perspective makes you less empathic and makes you not fully understand the drama of life, but I'm curious if any wise person has discussed this subject. Could someone suggest to me some reading?

Comment: A recent podcast of Pints with Aquinas the guest talked quite a bit about stoicism https://open.spotify.com/episode/247WlEVoEUvlrU1z9QHVbv?si=ba5b964bbc5a41d7 a bit more glowingly than the host was comfortable with for this exact reason and they hashed it out a bit.

Comment: Just my opinion: Stoicism is similar to Pharisaism in believing one can be good by strength of will. Original sin/radical corruption and salvation by grace contradict that boast. Not feeling in need of extreme mercy also tends to discourage promoting extreme mercy toward others.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, it makes total sense to me. I felt it when I let Catholicism be a bigger influence on me rather than stoicism, and then I started to be more empathic and not judge others.

Answer (score 1):

Stoicism as I understand it is a form of Platonism. It considers that the physical aspect of the world is somewhere between bad and trivial<sup>1</sup>. A person's suffering (as in Job's case) [should be disregarded](https://dailystoic.com/stoic-response-pain/) because it has no effect on the person's spirit, which is the more important part.

Christianity rejected this dichotomy with the heresies of [Docetism](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Docetism) and [gnosticism](https://www.britannica.com/topic/gnosticism). The early Christians emphasized that Christ was fully incarnated as a man - they featured it prominently in the [Nicene creed](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Nicene-Creed) at least partly to rebut those two heresies.

The Christian response to suffering isn't to ignore it but to be drawn closer to Christ through it. Historically, Christians have [embraced even martyrdom](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Saint-Ignatius-of-Antioch/Martyrdom-as-union-with-Christ).

The summary problem with Stoicism is that it rejects the pain and Christianity embraces the pain.

Job wasn't a Stoic because he fully acknowledged and dealt with his pain and he gave glory to God ([Job 1:21](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/job/1/21/s_437021)).

*<sup>1.</sup> I've heard this on podcasts from [Fr. Stephen De Young](https://www.ancientfaith.com/contributors/stephen_deyoung), but can't find a written source. That being the case, I could be mis-remembering and don't want to put words in his mouth. If anyone has a source (or contradiction) it would be helpful.*

Comment: Stoicism is not Platonism; they differ quite significantly on many points. Stoics are not gnostics either and don't see the material world as bad per se. They see good only in virtue. Stoicism on the one hand does say pain isn't an evil because it cannot harm one's virtue -- which is a point that should resonate with Christianity where the goal isn't to minimize pain per se; however, stoicism also tolerated suicide, sometimes for rather trivial amounts of suffering. This is their fatal flaw in their philosophy.

Comment: I don't think these heresies are related to this matter. Also, I think the difference is how stoics and Christians deal with the pain. Stoics can embrace the pain, like Seneca wanted his death to be more slowly and painful on purpose.

Comment: Also, some martyrs die after long tortures without saying anything, but some pray to Jesus to end their suffering soon. Praying wouldn't be seen as a good thing for stoics. Since they don't have control over the torturers or their bodies, only their reaction to it, they should despise all of this. It is easier said than done, of course.